# What may cause alex package build failure?

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, parallels, alex, ghcup

So I was trying to set up a Haskell project (`ghcup-hs` to be precise) but all attempts at building it, be it just `cabal run` or using HLS in VSCode, fail at alex package. In the terminal, it says "Building", my computer gets hot and loud, and then I just have to force quit the virtual machine since nothing is responding.

I believe it may have something to do with the fact I try to build it on my Ubuntu virtual machine (using Parallels Desktop) but I don't know much about Linux or virtual machines so will be glad to provide any relevant details.

Comment: Perhaps try to build natively on the mac?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Already tried that one, I got different set of problems (not related to alex package).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. are you trying to build `ghcup` from source?.

Comment: I am assuming you just want to have a `haskell` development environment within vscode. If that the case, you don't need to install `ghcup` from source

Comment: @lsmor I would like to contribute to ghcup so I try to build it from source

Comment: Oh that makes sense. How much RAM are you giving to the virtual machine?. Maybe it needs more. Also, which kind of problems do you have on your mac? I'd be worth to solve them first